# svn: '/svn/wib/!svn/bc/5634/wib/trunk/components' path not found

Tags: svn, svn-copy

We've recently migrated our SVN repository to a new server (but it still ran on the same domain) and made it unaccessible from http. We also used "--relocate" option of "svn switch" to point the working copy to the https URL instead of http.

After the move, we could run all SVN operations as part of our normal process, however when we try to create a new SVN tag, it gives the "svn: '/svn/wib/!svn/bc/5634/wib/trunk/components' path not found" error. The command that we are running (and it has run successfully in the past) is:

```
svn copy --parents -m "testing copying of files to SVN tag" https://svn.example.com/svn/wib/wib/trunk/components https://svn.example.com/svn/wib/wib/tags/test1/
```

Strangely, https://svn.example.com/svn/wib/wib/trunk/components is a valid path as we are able to open the repository in the browser. Plus, "svn log" (see below) on the above path runs ok.

```
svn log https://svn.example.com/svn/wib/wib/trunk/components@5634 | head -n1
```

I'm not sure how to further diagnose this problem and investigate the root-cause. I'll appreciate if any inputs can be provided to fix this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The SVN copy command you are running (URL to URL) is a server-side problem. You need to trace the error via the log on the server (None of the working copy logs are going to matter.)

I suspect there was an issue with the migration. Did you upgrade SVN versions? Did you dump and load or just rsync the repositories over? There are lots of variables server side you need to factor.